# Why ON CASCADE DELETE is not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete rows from 2 tables in one query, so I do:

```
DELETE FROM form_questionnaire;
```

This is removing all rows from `form_questionnaire` but leaves rows in `questionnaire`. Why rows in `questionnaire` are not removed if there is `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `form_questionnaire.questionnaire_id`?

**My tables**

```
CREATE TABLE questionnaire(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    content JSON,
    creator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE form_questionnaire(
    form_id INTEGER,
    questionnaire_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(form_id) REFERENCES form(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(questionnaire_id) REFERENCES questionnaire(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**database server**

MySQL 5.7.21-20

Comment: If You delete a form, the form is delete, if you delete the questionnaire, all related forms are deleted thanks to the constraint with delete cascade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking about cascades the wrong way around. What your current foreign key constraint is saying is "When you delete any row(s) in `questionnaire`, also delete any rows in *this* table (`form_questionnaire`) which reference those rows". That's the cascade.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I am understanding this incorrect OR it is your typing mistake. Foreign key will delete all rows from CHILD table (where FOREIGN KEY is defined) if related rows from master table are deleted.

That said, if you delete rows from `questionnaire` table, all related rows from `form_questionnaire` will be deleted automatically due to CASCADE DELETE.

What you have mentioned in question is opposite and does not happen so.